# Unable to import tensorflow_probability.substrates.jax

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jax, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to import tensorflow_probability.substrates.jax (specifically to use the distributions) and getting the error shown below (it looks like a self-import). I have installed tensorflow (2.8.2), tensorflow-probability (0.14.0) and jax (0.3.25).

Trying

```py
import tensorflow_probability.substrates.jax as tfp
```

I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'bijectors' from partially initialized module
'tensorflow_probability.substrates.jax' (most likely due to a circular import)
(/path-to-anaconda3-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_probability/substrates/jax/__init__.py)
```

I have tried a few different versions of tensorflow-probability with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it's due to version incompatibility. tensorflow_probability v0.14 was released in Sept 2021 ([history](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-probability/#history)), at which point JAX's most recent release was version 0.2.20 ([history](https://pypi.org/project/jax/#history)). JAX has has 36 releases since then, so it's not surprising that some incompatibilities may have arisen.

I tried in Google Colab and found that the following combination works:

```py
import tensorflow
import tensorflow_probability
import jax
print(f"{jax.__version__=}")
print(f"{tensorflow.__version__=}")
print(f"{tensorflow_probability.__version__=}")

import tensorflow_probability.substrates.jax as tfp
print("loaded!")
```

```
jax.__version__='0.3.25'
tensorflow.__version__='2.9.2'
tensorflow_probability.__version__='0.17.0'
loaded!
```

Another thing that can cause similar issues is if you are working in a notebook environment and installing new versions of packages that you've already imported. If you're working in notebooks, be sure to restart your Python runtime after you install or update a package.